# Android Java: Is there a way to programmatically launch a touch event to just the screen itself and not a view within my own app?

Tags: android, android-intent, touch-event

Suppose that I want to launch an activity from my new Android app like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        

        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.something.app");
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible for me to force a touch event at an (x, y) coordinate of my choosing on the device screen if the screen now displays another app? (The other app is not my own app by the way). For example, could I launch the com.something.app activity and then still trigger a touch event somewhere on the com.something.app activity? I looked up how to programmatically trigger touch events, and I found something like this:

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
  downTime,
  eventTime,
  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
  x,
  y,
  metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

However, notice that the last line view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent) requires there to be a view (within your own app) to launch the touch event to. I however, want to launch a touch event to just the Android screen itself (since another activity would be open).

Is there a way to do this? I suppose what I am asking is: Is there a way to programmatically launch a touch event to just the screen itself, and not a view within my own app?

Comment: No, for security reasons.  The only exception might be an accessibility app, or a rooted device.